# spring-xd job repository datasource enable oracle fast connection failover

Tags: java, spring, oracle, high-availability, spring-xd

In Spring-XD clustered environment, we are using Oracle as job repository datasource. Right now, this has been configured through servers.yml. But, we have to enable fast connection failover (FCF) for High availability (HA). Does current servers.yml support this? Or Is there a way to replace job repository data source with Oracle Pool DataSource with ONS configuration. Please advise me with any solution?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to configure your datasource like any spring datasource. 
did you try configure the datasource like this http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/current/reference/html/orcl.failover.html ?

you have to include your configuration like

```
datasource:
  url: jdbc:"jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(address_list=(address=(host=rac1)(protocol=tcp)(port=1521))(address=(host=rac2)(protocol=tcp)(port=1521)))(connect_data=(service_name=racdb1)))"
  username: sa
  password:
  driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  validationQuery: select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS
  fast-connection-failover-enabled:true
  ONS-configuration="rac1:6200,rac2:6200"
```

Let me know if that works, I am curious :)

Comment: Thanks a lot lake. By default Spring EDP using org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource for data source configuration. Looks like tomcat datasource does not have FCF and ONS-configuration properties.  Here is my local datasource properties

Comment: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@4ef31221{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver; maxActive=100; maxIdle=100; minIdle=10; initialSize=0; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=<my_password>; url=<url_replaced>; username=<my_username>; validationQuery=select 1 from dual;}

Comment: Do you think still default tomcat datasource supports FCF and ONS even though they were not visible on the above datasource properties?

Comment: you are right. I forgot that small "detail". I am guessing, but could you try modify the pool used in $SPRING_XD_HOME/xd/modules/common/jdbc-datasource.xml for something like https://qnatech.wordpress.com/2013/06/10/how-to-configure-jboss-datasource-oracleracre-connect/? adding the jar which contains the orlc definitions to the bin folder. I am not sure if spring xd is using this files to boot the pool configuration. The other option is build your own version and modify the pool used for the required which support FCF.

Comment: Thanks Lake. Spring XD does not use the config files from $SPRING_XD_HOME/xd/modules/common for booting the pool configuration. Also, I built my own custom datasource jar and put it in the classpath and configured xd-extensions in servers.yml. But, it loads after spring boot autoconfigure occured and does not override the default tomcat datasource. I am blocked here. Do you have any other thoughts??

Comment: ok after look for a few minutes, I found that the DB is being initialized here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-batch/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/batch/XdBatchDatabaseInitializer.java and the datasource is already in the context from here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/spring-xd-dirt/src/main/java/org/springframework/xd/dirt/server/admin/AdminServerApplication.java but I can't find the place where they are injecting the datasource, that is the place where you should change the bean to use orlc datasource

Comment: Thanks, Did you get a chance to take a look at the  /spring-xd-dirt/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring-xd/batch/batch.xml  for injecting datasource? Here, we did see the bean profile is 'admin', We are assuming that spring-xd admin module may perform all the DB operations on behalf of containers. The spring-xd containers may contact admin module via redis transport layer for any DB operations. Any thoughts?